DWG exports to PDF autoca attributes as comments
I exported dwg to pdf in autocad. All atributes are exported as a comments. This is not wanted. Can I Change this and not export atributtes as a comments to pdf?
I tried many formats to export but nothing helps and comments are still present in PDF format.
